# creating and changing parts of the created php file

Tags: php

I wonder what ist he best way to do the following.

I am creating a webseite CMS. Through CMS I am creating new folders with `index.php` files in them. For example I have created folder with the site `new_folder_name/index.php`
I wonder what ist the best way to  make an interaction between the created `index.php` files and database. For example I am creating the php file with another php file

```
<?php

$dir = "../new_folder_name";

$file_to_write = "index.php";

$content_to_write = '

 <?php 

 //// php code 

$foo=‘3‘:

 ?>

if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
 mkdir($dir);
}

$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

fwrite($file, $content_to_write);

fclose($file);

include $dir . '/' . $file_to_write;

?>
```

I am putting a variable `$foo` that needs to be changed with every new php file created. I could create `$foo=GET(´SOEMTHING´)` but this **GET** is making problems since this variable needs to be changed, and only for this file a unique value. I do not know if I explained it properly but I hope I did. In which way can I create a php file with specific **$foo** value or change the created file with php in order to get the **$foo** value which I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
$content_to_write = '
<?php 
 //// php code 
 $foo=\'$_GET[\'something\']\';
 ?>';
```

this is make your new script to read $_GET['something']

OR

this example, read this script's $_GET['something'] and put it's value in script...

```
$content_to_write = '
<?php 
 //// php code 
 $foo=\''.$_GET['something'].'\';
 ?>';
```

since you use single quote $_GET didn't get parse with original script. If you want to use that simply concatenate it. Alternatively you can concatinate '$' in between string to make variable just variables.